# How to take snapshot of PDF file in linux?

Tags: linux, pdf, snapshot

How I can take snapshot of first page of PDF file in Linux? I wanna do this on VPS server automaticaly. My distribution is Debian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can convert PDF pages if you have Ghostscript installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [PDFTK](http://www.pdfhacks.com/pdftk/). It's available in the Ubuntu repos, so check there first. 
The syntax you'll want to grab the first page is:

```
$  pdftk input.pdf cat 1 output out.pdf
```

Comment: The user may be referring to exporting pages as image files, like JPG or PNG, not extracting individual pages of a PDF file. Like how there is a camera tool on the FoxIt PDF Reader where you can just click on the page and the image is captured on your clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

Press & Hold **SHIFT + Print_screen** KEYS and with mouse select the rectangle of pdf page you want to take screenshot ...